# Apple Pay in a webshop

Tags: payment

just a quick question: is it possible to pay with ApplePay in a webshop (NOT via iPhone or Tablet but on a dekstop website) ? Or is Apple Pay exclusively for Mobile Devices? THX, Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, the question would be slightly out of topic here. Please add some details about the application or feature you are thinking of.

Comment: OK, no prob. I have to implement ApplePay in a Checkout Design/ smartphone View. I was wondering if I also have to adapt this Design for the desktop/ web view...it definitley is a UX issue because I have to think about an efficient flow for this

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic for this site

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2020, Apple Pay is only available on Safari Desktop. If you have a substantial number of users using Safari then I would definitely consider implementing ApplePay as a method of payment.